# windows 7 64-bit - can't upgrade upgrade to ruby 2.0 keeps showing 1.9.3 - can't switch to new installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, installation

I've looked through all of the topics on here and cannot find an answer.
All of the answers say to use RVM or PIK but I am on windows and pik is outdated/unusable.

When I deleted all of the ruby 1.9.3 files and typed ruby -v it showed my 2.0 was running.
However when I deleted the ruby files, rails 4.0 got uninstalled.

Everytime I reinstall rails from railsintsaller.org it reboots the 1.9.3

I tried switching the paths in computer > properties > advanced system settings but not sure if that helps or if I got it right.

It is really frustrating that the newest rails download overwrites the lates ruby files and knocks me back a version.

Can anyone help me I am on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit...not a lot of help for this system out there...

Comment: I think your path idea is closest. Can you rewrite the question providing details about your path and what values you tried in the path? That might get you some useful answers.

Comment: RVM doesn't work on Windows. It's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse,

Speaking from experience, Pik is a viable solution if you want to run both versions of Ruby on the same Windows box (at least until RVM 2 is released with Windows support). It should only require adding the Ruby from the RailsInstaller installation to Pik so that it is aware. Then, you should be able to use Pik and install other versions of Ruby.

The other option that is a bit more complicated is using Cygwin. This will actually allow you to install RVM and run it in a sandboxed Unix environment on Windows. It's something that I've been meaning to write up how to do but just haven't gotten around to it.

Cheers,
Evan